# HTML Page divided into two hlaves - two fullscreen responsive link images without JS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make a homepage divided into two halves. The page should look like [this page](http://www.nugget.cz) - two images should be responsive, they should cover full screen without white spaces on sides, images should be clickable. And I would appreciate if it could be written just in HTML and CSS without JavaScripts.

Everything I have got now is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="body">
      <div id="production" class="column half">
        <h1>production</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="label" class="column last">
        <h1>label</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and css

```
.body { overflow: hidden; margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
.column { float: left; }
.half { height: 100%; width: 50%; }
.last { height: 100%; float: none; width: auto; }
#production { background-image:url(bgprod.jpg); }
#label { background-image:url(bglabel.jpg); }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: give your 2 column halves 100% height, then position:absolute; with a z-index: -50; make sure you have html, body {margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;}

Comment: Do you have this rule: `html, body {margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;}` in your css?

Comment: Ok, wow, thanks! Now I have fullscreen, thanks. But what about full height of image? Can you help please? :)

Answer (score 0):

I sketched up something quickly that you can use.  This meets your requirements given that the images are proportional to the screen size.

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-half">
        <img class="responsive-image" src="test.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-half">
        <img class="responsive-image" src="test.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.container { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.col-half {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.responsive-image {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```